# C - Senitel controlled loop

Tags: c, loops

Assignment:

A - Write a program that gets numbers from user until user enters "-1". Then program should write numbers into a file.

I have done this, but I can not do the B one:

B - Update your program and print a histogram into the file like shown below. Save your code in a new file.

Example

report.dat:

5  *****
8  ********
11 ***********
3  ***

Code from A:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
    int num;
    const int senitel = -1;
    FILE*fileId;
    printf("Please enter integer number (-1 to finish)");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    fileId = fopen("report.dat", "w");
    while (num != senitel) {
      fprintf(fileId, "%d \n", num);
      scanf("%d", &num);      
    }

    fclose(fileId);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think you are only missing the stars at the end of each line, dont you? should not be that hard to cast the input number to an integer and create the amount of stars you need in a loop

Comment: these lines: scanf("%d", &num); should be written as: if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &num) ) { perror( "scanf" ); exit(1); }  Notice the leading ' ' in the format string to cause scanf to step over/consume white space (like newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the user input directly to the file, you need to store it in a data structure temporarily. When the user enters the sentinel value, then output the contents of the data structure.

in pseudocode

```
ask user for input
while not sentinel
    add to array[user value]++
    get next input

for each element in array
    if value > 0
        fprintf value + " "

        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
            fprintf "*"

        fprintf
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do both steps in one stage (area) in code.  Separate the file operations to a later stage, and use variables to store your histogram values, and write the variables to file.  You can store the Entered Number in one array, and the Count of that Number in another array - or combine both into a `struct` and create an array of the `struct`.  Use `typedef` to make a type from your new `struct`.

Like this (incomplete but will get you started):

```
typedef struct tag_HistogramRow {
   long EnteredNumber;
   long Count;
} t_HistogramRow;

t_HistogramRow *typMyHistogram=NULL; // Pointer to type of t_HistogramRow, init to NULL and use realloc to grow this into an array
long lHistArrayCount=0;
```

Your first step creates this array, grows it as necessary, fills in the values and waits for -1

Second step writes all the stored data to file.

Answer (score 0):

```
the lines:

while (num != senitel) {
  fprintf(fileId, "%d \n", num);
  scanf("%d", &num);      
}

would become:

while (num != senitel) 
{
    // echo num to file
    fprintf(fileId, "%d ", num);

    // echo appropriate number of '*' to file
    for( int i= 0; i<num; i++ )
    { 
        fprintf( fileId, "*" );
    } // end if

    // echo a newline to file
    fprintf( fileId, "\n" );

    // be sure it all got written to file before continuing
    fflush( fileId ); 

    // note: leading ' ' in format string enables white space skipping
    if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &num) ) 
    { // then, scanf() failed
        perror( "scanf" ); // also prints out the result of strerror( errno )
        exit(1);
    }  // end if     
} // end while
```